JHipster 8.5 get remote IP address from request
I need to obtain the IP of the request that reaches the Resource for business validation purposes. Please help if someone has done it.
I have tried:
String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
String ipAddress1 = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");

But in the first case, it returns the address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, and in the second case it returns null.

Looks like your application is behind a proxy,
Couple of things you need to do.

make sure the proxy you're using is forwarding the headers you need,
EG config in nginx:




location / {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_read_timeout 7200s;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        client_max_body_size 200M;
    }


If above doesnot work, try adding following config in addition to above to your spring properties

server.forward-headers-strategy= native

The first option worked perfectly.

Great, could you accept it as an answer then
